# No remoted actions found to resolve after rerender

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript-remoting

i am creating a select element in visualforce and making its options using remote visualforce
     //cant give complete code but its returning a list string

```
  @RemoteAction 
   public static List<String> getFlowList(){
      List<String> x = new List<String>(ss);
   return x;
}
```

in visualforce a small snippet of code is

```
      <tr><td style="text-align:right"> Flow Name :</td><td>
      <select id="flowList" style="margin-left:10px"></select>
      </td>
      </tr>
      <tr><td>
              <apex:commandButton id="submitBtn" value="Submit" style="text-align:right;" onclick="ClickEventHandler()" rerender="form"/>
      </td>
      </tr>
 window.onload =function(){
        console.log('coming here');
        Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction(
        '{!$RemoteAction.Sample.getFlowList}',function(result, event){
               console.log('result is');
               console.log(result);
               var options='';

               for(var x=0;x< result.length;x++)
                  options+='<option value='+result[x]+'>'+result[x]+'</option>';
                  document.getElementById('flowList').innerHTML = options;       
        });

        }
```

after clicking button its give me visualforce error

```
No remoted actions found to resolve '$RemoteAction.Sample.getFlowList'
Error is in expression '{!$RemoteAction.Sample.getFlowList}' in component <apex:form> in page sample
```

can any one please tell why i am facing this error and how to resolve it ??

Comment: What is your class name ?

Comment: Sample is my class name

Comment: when page comes first its showing no error issue is when button is clicked and its rerender.

Comment: .Normally I dont recommend using ReRender With Javascript remoting .But as an alternative you can load the body again on ReRender with Window.onload in putput Pannel and Render the same

Answer (score 4):

In your VF Page, check the controller attribute, whether it points to your Apex class. After pointing my VF page to the controller it started working fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

I also faced the same problem. I then tried re-rendering some dummy block of the page which i didnot require to be shown on the page(set rendered="false"). The error is gone now and my code works fine!

```
<apex:selectList id="someList" value="{!selectedContentId}" >
    <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!doSearch}" reRender="block1" />
    <apex:selectoption id="none" itemValue="red" itemLabel="Red" />
</apex:selectList>
<apex:pageBlock id="block1" rendered="false">
    Hi
</apex:pageBlock>
```

Comment: Sonam, if possible can you add some code sample to explain this

Comment: <apex:selectList id="someList" value="{!selectedContentId}" >
    <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!doSearch}" reRender="block1" />
     <apex:selectoption id="none" itemValue="red" itemLabel="Red" />
</apex:selectList>
<apex:pageBlock id="block1" rendered="false">
    Hi
    </apex:pageBlock>

Answer (score -1):

To resolve this, you method in the controller should have the

> @RemoteAction

annotation like the one below,

```
global with sharing class AccountRemoter {

    public String accountName { get; set; }
    public static Account account { get; set; }
    public AccountRemoter() { } // empty constructor

    @RemoteAction
    global static Account getAccount(String accountName) {
        account = [SELECT Id, Name, Phone, Type, NumberOfEmployees 
                   FROM Account WHERE Name = :accountName];
        return account;
    }
}
```

Also, for more details just follow the [Javascript Remoting Example](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_js_remoting_example.htm)